# Where can I find the latest java update for Mac OS systems prior to 10.6?

Tags: leopard, java, macos, malware

I have a couple of old Macs that run old versions of Mac OSX and I want to protect them from the recent Flashback malware. 
Has Apple produced a java update for systems Prior to 10.6 (snow leopard)? 
Can I get such an update anywhere else?

Link:http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4297?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
This link seems to say the latest update is only for OSX 10.6
I think there is an update for Lion (10.7) as well, what about leopard (10.5) or Tiger (10.4)?

Comment: If such an update exists, you would get it via System Update.

Answer (score 1):

The Java updates for OS X come from Apple, not Oracle (that "owns" Java and provides downloads for Windows and Linux). In general, Apple doesn't seem to support OS X versions prior to 10.6 (that's something like an unofficial policy, they seem to support the latest 2 versions only), so in general you can't get official Apple updates for anything, including Java, for 10.5 and below. There were ideas about some open source substitutes for Java, but I am not sure what happened to them. Given the recent Java issues, Apple may decide to create and distribute Java update for 10.5, but I won't bet on that.